# Problems primary links translate drupal 6

Tags: routes, i18n-l10n

I have translate the link in my menu (primary links) in spanish, when i change the language from italian to spanish all the voices of the menu are translated except one ( the voice **apartamentos**) that is not visible but is right activated and setting as the other links.
Do you know something?

Comment: Ok I have flush all caches and it's right....sorry!!

Answer (score 1):

I flush all the caches and the problem dont exist!